# Is there a way to open a PuTTY session to a specific tty?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, terminal, putty

I use PuTTY to connect to Ubuntu Server 12.04 from Windows 7 SP1, and during Ubuntu boot, I have tasks in various tty's.

- When I log in using PuTTY, then issue `tty`, the response is `/dev/pts/1`
- I have installed `linuxvnc` in Ubuntu, using RealVNC on Windows to view these tty's, but I prefer PuTTY because it has some issues.

Is there a way to log in directly to `/dev/tty2`, or failing that, switch to `tty2` from within the current PuTTY session?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `screen` command:

```
screen /dev/tty2
```

Comment: So...   Abandon putty? Can putty not do this? I already have 7 tty sessions running, and I would rather not reconfigure my entire world by going back and asking each of those to startup in screen.

Comment: Just run the `screen` command in PuTTY.