# How do I use PuTTY to interact with a service running on /dev/tty2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, putty, systemd, tty

Okay, so I have a program (which I did not write and cannot modify) which I am running as a service using `systemd` on my Ubuntu 16.04 cloud server. It's working great, *except* that I need to be able to interact with the running program, and the only way the program supports interacting with it is via `stdin`/`stdout`. I realize it's pretty unconventional for a service to use only command-line input, but I don't see what other choice I have.

From what I've read [here](https://alan-mushi.github.io/2014/10/26/execute-an-interactive-script-at-boot-with-systemd.html), it's possible to tell a service to use TTY for `stdin` and `stdout`, and so I *think* I've setup my service to do just that:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service
After=getty@tty2.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/my/service
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty2
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
User=username

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Once my service is running (and yes, it's definitely running), I try using the `screen` command in PuTTY to view `/dev/tty2` as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1177614/putty-to-specific-tty):

`sudo screen /dev/tty2`

However, when I do that all I see in PuTTY is a blank screen with no output that I cannot interact with. (And yes, the program generates plenty of output while running.)

So I'm not sure where I've gone wrong, whether it's in the configuration of the service, my usage of the `screen` command, or with PuTTY itself. I'm not a super experienced user of Linux in general and this is my first time doing anything with TTY, so my understanding is pretty thin.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally untested (yet), might work though.

After you log in (via SSH with PuTTY or whatever), start a new `tmux` session (I use `tmux`, but you can choose `screen`), as if you'd like to work in a shell within it. The plain command `tmux` will work but let's name the session:

```
tmux new-session -s foo
```

Then find the PID of your `service`:

```
pidof service
```

and use `reptyr` to attach it to your current terminal which is inside `tmux` (I guess you may need `sudo` as well). See [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1231033/432690) for short characteristics of `reptyr` and what to do to make it work.

```
reptyr <pid>
```

If you want to log out, first detach from `tmux` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> (for `screen` it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>). Later you can return to that terminal with

```
tmux attach-session -t foo
```

so there's no need to use `reptyr` again until after the next reboot.

---

If I were you I would try to run the service inside `tmux` in the first place, I expect this would straightforwardly bind it to TTY provided by `tmux` without TTY-related `systemd` settings. See this: [*How to run `tmux`/`screen` with `systemd` > 230?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/802189/693277)

Something like:

```
…
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s foo /path/to/my/service
User=username
…
```

If this works, you will have to run `tmux attach-session …` as the right user:

```
sudo -u username tmux attach-session -t foo
```